# Trying to build this small demo using poppler fails to compile but poppler.h is found?

Tags: c++, poppler

I found a short c++ example on stack overflow that extracts text from a pdf using c++ poppler, but cannot find any call to extract the images.

I have a pdf which is a sequence of scans from a copier. I would like to open them one after another

```
#include <iostream>

#include "poppler-document.h"
#include "poppler-page.h"
#include "poppler-image.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    poppler::document *doc = poppler::document::load_from_file("./test1dld_scan.pdf");
    const uint32_t num_pages = doc->pages();
    cout << "page count: " << num_pages << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_pages; ++i) {
        const auto page = doc->create_page(i);
        if (!page) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to create the page." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        auto images = page-> // right here....

}
```

There is a poppler::image class, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation where I can get it out. There is no mention of image in the document, and none on the page either.

Comment: You need to link your binary with the library (`g++ ... -lpoopler` perhaps?)

Comment: Does `poppler.h` declare these functions? Does your sample code match version of your poppler version? Did they maybe change the names?

Comment: Ok, forget poppler c, maybe way too old. Switching to c++ and cleaning up the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
I am not aware of any API to extract the actual image from a PDF file.
But the renderer can render your pdf to any desired DPI. Of course, I would like the DPI to match the resolution of the image inside.

I have a pdf of scanned images. I render it at 300 dpi and it works:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "poppler-document.h"
#include "poppler-page.h"
#include "poppler-page-renderer.h"
#include "poppler-image.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace poppler;

int main() {
    const int DPI = 300;
    document *doc = document::load_from_file("./test.pdf");
    const uint32_t num_pages = doc->pages();
    cout << "page count: " << num_pages << endl;

    page_renderer renderer;
    renderer.set_render_hint(page_renderer::text_antialiasing);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pages; ++i) {
        
        const auto page = doc->create_page(i);
        if (!page) {
            cerr << "Unable to create the page." << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        image img = renderer.render_page(page,DPI,DPI);
        cout << "created image of  " << img.width() << "x"<< img.height() << "\n";
        img.save("page"+to_string(i)+".png", "png", DPI);
    }
}
```

Comment: The scanner obviously has a resolution. It puts the images into the pdf. While I can experimentally figure it out, it would be nice if there were some programmatic way to see the scale of the image in the document. But the poppler API does not support asking for a bitmap inside that I can see. All I can do is render the document at a resolution, and if it looks bad, then it's not an integer multiple of the underlying image. If the page is 8.5x11 inches, and the image is 2550x3300, then I know it's 300 DPI. Is there any way to find that out?

Comment: @KJ I want to know how to extract the SIZE of the image. If I know the size of my pdf (8.5x11) and I know that each page is a scanned bitmap, and I know that the size of that bitmap is 2550x3300, then I can calculate the DPI myself. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an API to give me the image, I can extract text, but the only way I see to view the image is to render the page. Am i wrong?